# CSS %width of 'container available space'?

Tags: css

I have an example:

HTML:

```
.root
   .pc25
   .pc25
   .pc25
   .pc25

(inside class 'pc25' has contents)
```

Now, in CSS I have:

```
.root
  width: 400px
  padding: 0 10%
  .pc25
    width: 25%
```

Right now, divs with 'pc25' class have 100px of width each. Is there any way that I cam make their width 90px? ( 'container available space' = 360px ) (cause padding is 10%) (360/4=90)

Comment: Ehm... a 400px parent with a padding of 10% is still 400px wide. Giving it a padding won't make it shrink.

Comment: Sorry for that... The purpose here is for every .pc25 have 90px of width.. If you know what I mean...

Comment: @MrLister - not necessarily accurate, if the parent `box-sizing` is set to `border-box`, then the width is *inclusive* of padding.

Comment: @cale_b There is no box-sizing in the OP's example, and the default is content-box.

Comment: @MrLister - both of your statements are true, but that's making an **assumption** about OP's situation, which is not always safe, especially if using a framework such as Twitter Boostrap (I know, no tag, but again - askers don't always ask good questions with good tags).  OP *hints* that there is a problem by indicating available space is only 360px....

Comment: @LanMai If you want it to be 90px wide, then just give it a width of 90px. Occam's razor.

Comment: They will automatically only be 25% of available width. Nothing to do here.

Comment: Wait, we have bigger problems. The 10% padding is not 10% of 400px, but 10% of the available space for the root. So it depends on how wide your window is.

Comment: Your understanding of how %-based padding works is wrong. The percentage does not relate to the element's width, but to its parent width. See mdn * <percentage> With respect to the width of the containing block.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Comment: That is not CSS or HTML syntax. Please post the compiled HTML and CSS, or, if your question is about a problem *within the preprocessors you are using*, include those preprocessor tags.

Comment: Right. If the problem is indeed that 25% turns out too wide to get all 4 children on 1 line, the problem could be with the box-sizing, or it could be something else. Maybe you have spaces between the chuldren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use just the "content box" instead of the entire width of the div.

If you are using CSS3 and don't need to worry about backwards browser compatibility you can use the `calc()` functionality (spec [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc))

Then you can do `width: calc(25% - 10px)`

But as you can see... it might be wiser to manually adjust the percentage you are assigning your elements. If you know the padding is always going to take 10% of your elements width, I would subtract 2.5% from each of your smaller divs. So instead of giving them all 25%, you would give them 2.5%. This would shrink all of them by 10px if your parent is 400px.

On top of that, this is a responsive solution! All around a good way to do it. Sadly you DO have to manually adjust % size to account for padding at this point.

Edit: Since your padding is 10% of the root... this got trickier. If you are looking for a responsive solution you may have to adjust how you are setting padding.